# Preview pdf with http headers

Tags: javascript, html, api, pdf

I'm trying to preview a pdf in the browser with just this HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 clearfix">
    <object width="100%" height="600px" data="<%- model.pdf %>" type="application/pdf">
        <p>It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. <a href="<%- model.pdf %>">Click here to download the PDF</a>. Or <a href="http://get.adobe.com/reader/" target="_blank">click here to install Adobe Reader</a>.</p>
        <embed width="100%" height="600px" src="<%- model.pdf %>" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Where model.pdf is an url that I generate to request it from there.

**The problem:**

I'm working in a full javascript/fe project that is consumer of an API. As client, I need a token and some more things to request data from the API that I have to set in the headers of every call.

So what I need is, somehow to set those headers somewhere.

**My question:**

Is is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just load the PDF in an iFrame?

Comment: Yes, I can but first I need to request it with the proper http headers, otherwise it will give me a 401 (Unauthorized) error

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear: You can use a PHP script that will pretend to be a PDF and just load the PDF-file from the API using PHP. And then load that PHP file in an iframe. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) will be useful for you.

> The object structure of PDF.js loosely follows the structure of an
> actual PDF. At the top level there is a document object. From the
> document, more information and individual pages can be fetched. To get
> the document:
>
> ```
> PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf')
> ```

For headers try this:

```
var 
    obj = {};

obj.url = 'url_to_your_file.pdf';
obj.httpHeaders = {
    
    "X-Header": "VALUE"
};
  
PDFJS.getDocument(obj).then(function(pdf) {
  
    // your code
});
```

You read more about `DocumentInitParameters` [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191008054727/https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/global.html).

Comment: Is there any example where they are requesting it with headers?